# Can someone explain for me what is the meaning of the following code

Tags: java, string, computer-science, string-matching

I have two question about this code, hope someone can explain them for me and I would appreciate for that! It's a question about I/D string match.

description:
Given a string S that only contains "I" (increase) or "D" (decrease), let N = S.length.

Return any permutation A of [0, 1, ..., N] such that for all i = 0, ..., N-1:

If S[i] == "I", then A[i] < A[i+1]
If S[i] == "D", then A[i] > A[i+1]

question 1. Why we need to put 'a[n]=low' there.

question 2. According to the input 'IDID' we know that we have 4 elements but why we get 5 values in the end?

```
class Solution {
    public int[] diStringMatch(String S) {
        int n=S.length();
        int low=0;
        int high=n;
        int[] a= new int[n+1];
            for(int i=0; i<S.length(); i++){
                if(S.charAt(i)=='I'){
                    a[i]=low++;

                }
                else{
                    a[i]=high--;

                }

            }
           a[n]=low;
                 return a;
    }

}
```

Input: "IDID"
Output: [0,4,1,3,2]

Comment: String s is of length 4, and n will be 4, but when creating the array int[] a= new int[n+1]; so you are creating an array of length 5

Comment: Consider an example when your string is "I". It means that you should print 2 elements in increasing order, namely [0, 1]. So the number of elements is string length + 1.

Comment: @dyukha  So are you saying if we saw the condition like If S[i] == "I", then A[i] < A[i+1] or S[i] == "D", then A[i] > A[i+1] which means we need to increase the array length by 1?.

Comment: @dyukha One more thing sir. Why it's a[n]=low instead of a[n+1]=low

Comment: @Abi   Thanks for your reply, one more thing sir. Why it's a[n]=low instead of a[n+1]=low

Comment: Your array A is n+1 long (0-N), so the last index is n. That line is just filling in the last remaining number.

Comment: @AjahnCharles thank you very much sir, fully appreciate.